# What is Search Unit in Azure Cognitive search?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-cognitive-search

What is search unit in Azure cognitive search?
Need more details about internal process Search Unit.

What is the advantage of more than one search unit in Azure cognitive search?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Cognitive Search allows you to add redundancy and partitioning to your service.

With redundancy, the data in your index exists in multiple copies. The main advantage of that is failure tolerance.

With partitioning, the data is split into shards. The main advantage of that is performance as requests can be routed and handled with more parallelism.

Search units are the product of partitions and redundancy, pretty much how many virtual machines are needed to achieve the specified numbers.